# Error trying to add border to TableRow

Tags: android, tablerow, xml-drawable

I've found lots of examples of this and as far as I can tell I'm doing it right, but I still get an error.  I've created a border.xml file and put it into a drawable folder.  The folder didn't exist, so I had to create it.  I have a feeling my problem is where I saved the file or possibly that I need to register it somewhere.  Here you can see the file.
[image]

Here is the code for border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#515151"/>
  <corners android:radius="3dp" />
  <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="5dp"
    android:right="10dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

And here is how I'm trying to use it

```
<TableRow 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/border.xml"
    android:padding="5dp">
```

The error I get is:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value 
 '@drawable/border.xml').
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `android:background="@drawable/border"` without the `.xml`